# Package.appxmanifest Settings for a Apache Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid App

Tags: html, cordova, windows-store-apps, appxmanifest

How does one set project specific settings for a hybrid app? I understand that the config.xml file provides some support using both the "preference" and "platform" elements, but there doesn't appear to be a definition as to what the possible values are.

How, for example, would I add wide tile support for a Windows Store output? In a native Windows Store project, I would specify the appropriate "VisualElements" element in the package.appxmanifest file. What are the mappings between package.appxmanifest and config.xml?

Comment: It seems to me that the manifest files are generated automatically when you build the app. Try building then search the project for AppxManifest and you should see the XML file showing up in the bin folder. The only thing is I'm not sure how to change the values of the generated AppxManifest file, because for me it only shows placeholder variables instead of my details (e.g. $username% instead of my username).

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog entry tonight and tried it and it works. The instructions refer to VS2013. For those trying this in VS2015, I had to create the "cert" folder as mentioned below. Also, these instructions mention a "windows8" folder. In VS2015 the two platform folders for Windows are "windows" and "wp8" (under the other "res" subfolders, anyway). To err on the side of caution, I created those two folders, plus a "windows8" folder. I then created the xml file as specified below, edited it, and copied it to all locations.

When I built, my generated appxmanifest reflected the updated values.

http://sonyarouje.com/tag/cordova/

> 1. Create a Package.appxmanifest file under res/cert/windows8. Create a windows8 solution folder if not exist.
> 2. Open the project folder and go to bld/windows-AnyCpu/Debug and open AppxManifest.xml in notepad, copy the content and paste it in the above Package.appxmanifest file.
> 3. Double click on Package.appxmanifest file then goto Capabilities tab and choose ‘Private Networks (Client & Server)’.
> 4. Save it and run the app again, this time it worked